# Zip all the files of a folder in the same folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to zip all the files from a folder and places it in the same folder. Below is my code:

```
import os as __os
import zipfile

def zipdir(path, ziph):
    for root, dirs, files in __os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            print(file)
            ziph.write(__os.path.join(root, file))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    zip_name = 'test.zip'
    working_directory = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\gaz"
    archive_name = __os.path.join(working_directory, zip_name)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(archive_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
        zipdir(working_directory + '', zipf)
```

I am trying to create zip of all the files inside a folder. I am expecting the code to create a zip in the same folder. Its going into infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see an endless loop but you're including the newly created `test.zip` (empty) to the archive of the same name.

It would be better to check file before adding it to the archive:

```py
def zipdir(path, ziph):
    for root, dirs, files in __os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file != zip_name:
                print(file)
                ziph.write(__os.path.join(root, file))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `zipdir()` funciton is calling itself recursively, resulting in the infinite loop. Try `zipf.write()`. That function adds a file to a zip archive.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(archive_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
        for root, dirs, files in __os.walk(working_directory):
            for file in files:
                if os.path.samefile(archive_path, os.path.join(root, file)):
                    continue
                zipf.write(__os.path.join(root, file))
```

Edit: Check if `archive_name` file is located in `working_directory`

Comment: Can you point the line where `zipdir` calls itself?

Comment: Well there isn't a specific line, where you actively call the recursion, but you want to save the zip to the same directory you are iterating over and so the zip keeps trying to add itself to the zip, like @Tranbi said in his answer.

Comment: And how is you solution addressing this problem?

Comment: Kinda forgot about this answer. Now it does.